# My user ID appears in the search box automatically

Tags: support, profile-page, search

When I click on my Stack Overflow profile icon (as shown in the image below) the user ID appears in the search box automatically, Doesn't that seem odd? Or is this expected?

[image: Search box with user id]

Comment: They do it so you can search your own posts quickly and easily. If you're on your profile, it's assumed that you're looking through _your_ account. If you decide to search something else, `ctrl` + `a` is a pretty quick key combo to make, then you just type what you're wanting. (But yes, it's intentional.) Note that this also works for the profiles of others- If you go to my profile, _my_ id will be auto-populated to make searching my posts easier.

Comment: Check out this answer to the same question on Meta Stack Exchange, from an employee of SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106148/266735

Answer (score 13):

Definitely by design. Also happens if you look at *anyone else's* profile. As Kendra mentioned in the comments, this allows you to search for someone's posts without having to type (or copy-paste) their user ID.

Speaking for myself, I often find posts that I've previously read by searching for keywords in the posts of people I thought might've been the author. Given the number of similar questions, this can save a *lot* of time sifting through near-duplicates for that one answer by VonC.

For searching *your own* posts, you can also type `user:me` into the search box, which is nice if you don't remember your own user ID or have a really long one or never learned to type numbers properly *and* also have enough posts that you need to search them. But of course, this won't work for searching anyone else's posts, so the profile-page shortcut is much appreciated in those situations.

### See also: [Search field on a users' page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106138/search-field-on-a-users-page)